# Getting sum from key value pair using List in C#

Tags: c#

I have following code

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();

list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Cat", 1));
list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Cat", 2));
list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Rabbit", 4));
```

Now I am trying to pass `"Cat"` and I should get sum of these keys in a variable.If I pass Rabbit, pass only that number

How to get this ? thinking of for-each....

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "If Keys are not equal, pass only that number"

Comment: Would a Dictionary better fit your needs?

Comment: What's your call on this? Did you try anything? Did it work? What issue did you face?

Comment: I just thought about list and written code. Which is best? list or Dictionary

Comment: Use a real class instead of `KeyValauePair`, for example a `Pet` class. Then store these pets in a `List<Pet>`. I guess the value is the age, so you could provide a property `DateTime Birthdate`. The `Age` property would be calculated: `int Age => DateTime.Today.Year - Birthdate.Year;`.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a `Linq` appraoch with `Where()` and `Sum()`

```
int result = list.Where(x => x.Key == "Cat").Sum(x => x.Value);
```

or

```
int result = list.Sum(x => x.Key == "Cat" ? x.Value : 0);
```

Comment: if I pass "Rabbit", it will get only that number ( ie 4) ?

Comment: @aniltc You could try it

Comment: new to LInq @Paparazzi

Comment: @aniltc: That doesn't stop you from trying it though, does it? Curiosity is important for learning things.